# Creating a macro to fill out an online form, loop is set up incorrectly

Tags: vba

This is the middle of the block of code, where I've added a loop to access each cell and transfer its value to a variable.

I have omitted the part of the code where I create the IE object, access the website, etc. because it appears to be working correctly. The loop is what I'm not sure of.

What do I need to change?

```
Dim name As String
Dim address As String
Dim city As String
Dim state As String
Dim zip As String
Dim phone As String

Range.Row = i

    For i = 2 To 626

        name = Cells(A, i).Value
        address = Cells(B, i).Value
        city = Cells(C, i).Value
        state = Cells(D, i).Value
        zip = Cells(E, i).Value
        phone = Cells(F, i).Value

        IE.Document.all("butAdd").Click
        If IE.Document.Title = " PestPac - Maintain Notification Locations" Then
        IE.Document.getElementById("Name").Value = name
        IE.Document.getElementById("Address").Value = address
        IE.Document.getElementById("City").Value = city
        IE.Document.getElementById("State").Value = state
        IE.Document.getElementById("Zip").Value = zip
        IE.Document.getElementById("Phone").Value = phone
        IE.Document.getElementById("Distance").Value = "0.1"

        IE.Document.all("butAdd").Click

        Exit For

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `End If` statement at the end of your `If` statement after the `Exit for`. You can also add an `Else` if you want it do something differently if the Document title is something else.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look at that now.